# How Upload image to Server() via RestTemplate Client and Server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am using RestTemplate Client Code and Want to access Image on Server side. I want to upload image on custom Directory of Tomcat, i am getting error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity] and content type [multipart/form-data]
```

RestTemplate Client Code:

```
public String saveCompanylogo(File file){
        String url = COMPANY_URL+ "/saveCompanyLogo";
        MultipartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity ();
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file) ;
        //Prepare payload
        multiPartEntity.addPart("file", fileBody) ;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        HttpEntity<MultipartEntity> entity = new HttpEntity<MultipartEntity>    (multiPartEntity, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> exchange = restTemplate.exchange(url,     HttpMethod.POST, entity,  new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {
        });
        return exchange.getBody();
    }
```

My Server side(Controller) code is :

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/saveCompanyLogo")
    @Consumes("multipart/form-data")
    public String saveCompanylogo(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file)         {
      System.out.println(""+file);   
     //Todo coding
     return "stringData";
    }
```

Comment: I use `FileSystemResource` instead of `FileBody`. And server receives `InputStream`

Comment: This is not working from my side.Can you Attach you code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `FileSystemResource` instead of `FileBody`. This is my code:

```
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());

Map params = new LinkedMultiValueMap();
params.put("file", new FileSystemResource(file));
HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
HttpEntity requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(params, httpHeaders);
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);
```

And in server side (I use Jersey instead of MVC, but I guess no matters):

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/saveCompanyLogo")
@Consumes("multipart/form-data")
public String saveCompanylogo(@RequestParam("file") InputStream file) {
    //DO SOMETHING
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: How can i set HttpEntity<FormParams> , How it is possible , because we are passing LinkedMultiValueMap params in "new HttpEntity<>(params, httpHeaders);"  And when i use "HttpEntity<FormParams> ," getting alert : "FormParams cannot be resolved to a type" but if i use :HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(params, headers); getting error at runtime: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided

Comment: Sry, my fault. Remove `FormParams`

Comment: I tried several other answers but none of them helped me, i had to use "FileSystemResource" and pass the converted file there (with a method i have that converts MultiPartFile to File)

Comment: ```java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource cannot be cast to class java.util.List``` at ```params.put("file", new FileSystemResource(file));```

Comment: Same error as Magno above here, ClassCastException